# For foursquare support: What is the ip address for the server that sends real time pushes?

Tags: push, foursquare

Currently, I'm writing a foursquare app which uses the real time push feature. However, the webserver that I am developing it on is behind a firewall which requires ip's to be whitelisted in order to get through.

Unfortuately, I have no other way to figure this out since I cant see the firewall logs. (We all know and love the IT department...)

If you guys aren't comfortable giving out that information here, perhaps you could pm me?

Thanks.

Comment: is this the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167713/what-is-the-ip-addresss-range-for-foursquare-api

Answer (score 0):

Push requests originate from Amazon's EC2 cluster in US-East. You can see the range of IP addresses here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1351

We're working to transition to a smaller set of static IP addresses. We will document those on the [developer site](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime) when this is done.